# Install PHP 5.6.2 (specific version) and mysql 5.6.17 in Ubuntu OS

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Install PHP 5.6.2 (specific version) and mysql 5.6.17 in Ubuntu OS. There are ways to install LAMP, but i am looking for the specific versions. Please guide me..

OS version: Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

You can install any version using *apt-get* in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>
```

You can list the versions by using this command:

```
apt-cache showpkg <package-name>
```

Comment: I have already installed the LAMP which i having the latest version. Is that possible to do it in LAMP itself (PHP 5.6.2 (specific version) and mysql 5.6.17 )..

Comment: You need to remove your current PHP and MySQL, then reinstall the version you need.

Comment: This post maybe can help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/498175/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-9-to-5-4-in-ubuntu-14-04-installed-with-lamp

Comment: You can try downloading PHP source and building it yourself the version you need.

Comment: php-5.6.2.tar.gz if i download like this, how can i install this particualr file

Comment: @ShyjuPulari You need to extract it. Then change to the directory (probably php-5.6.2), after that you need to configure it with "./configure", you can get the list of the configuration options via "./configure --help". After you configured it run "make", after it finished install it "make install". But i still recommend using the apt-get to make this easier.